# Android Activity in Background display alertdialog leds to crash

Tags: android

I had open an application activity A.Now i press the home Button after some time through a webservice call i try to display the message in alertdialog on Activity A.Then i try to open the application by clicking the application icon the application get force close.The one thing i noted here is it calls the activity onCreate(). can any one give me suggestion?

Comment: post code rather than explaining whole scenario... its much easier..

Comment: fisrt thing paste your error log and secondly paste your code how you are doing it

Answer (score 2):

You cannot show an `AlertDialog` without any `UserInterface`, instead you can try to show AlertDialog inside `onResume()` so it pops up when your Activity `restarts/resumes`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not click the back button (then app exits), and when you open again, see if it still force closes. Then you can find the reason. 
A bit difficult to tell unless we see code